# SQL query showing just few DISTINCT records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following records:

```
Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3
------+-------+------
  A   |   A   | XYZ01
  A   |   A   | XYZ02
  A   |   A   | XYZ03
  A   |   B   | XYZ04
  B   |   B   | XYZ05
  B   |   B   | XYZ06
  B   |   B   | XYZ07
  B   |   B   | XYZ08
```

I need a query which will return maximum of 2 records where Col_1 and Col_2 are distinct (regardless of Col_3) (that should be like 2 records sample of each distinct col_1,col_2 combination).

So this query should return:

```
Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3
------+-------+------
  A   |   A   | XYZ01
  A   |   A   | XYZ02
  A   |   B   | XYZ04
  B   |   B   | XYZ05
  B   |   B   | XYZ06
```

Comment: Have you tried any queries of your own yet?

Comment: Firstly I meant about Oracle, but it would be nice to have such a query for MySQL

Comment: @sbrbot did any of the answers satisfy your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT col_1
        ,col_2
        ,col_3
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY col_1
            ,col_2 ORDER BY col_1
            ) AS foo
    FROM TABLENAME
    )  bar
WHERE foo < 3
```

Top command will not work because you want to 'group by' multiple columns. What will help is partitioning the data and assigning a row number to the partition data. By partitioning on col_1 and col_2 we can create 3 different groupings.

1.All rows with 'a' in col_1 
 2.All rows with 'b' in col_2 
 3 All rows with 'a' and 'b' in col_1,col_2

we will order by col_1 (I picked this because your result set was ordered by a). Then for each row in that grouping we will count the rows and display the row number.

We will use this information as a derived table, and select * from this derived table where the rownumber is less than 3. This will get us the first two elements in each grouping

Comment: It's pretty close to ANSI compatible if not entirely. Derived tables and window functions are both standard.

Comment: @MartinSmith I have removed those comments as you are correct.

Comment: @martinsmith Cool, I didnt know that it was. I just looked up if row_number and the partition by clause were ansi sql. And they are right. I guess you could copy this over to oracle and have it run. Thank you Martin!

Comment: @gh9 IIRC Oracle doesn't allow `AS` to introduce a derived table alias but apart from that it should basically work in both Oracle and Postgres AFAIK. You could test in SQL Fiddle if interested!

Answer (score 0):

as far as Oracle The use of Rank would work.

```
Select * From (SELECT Col_1 ,
   Col_2 ,
   Col_3 ,
   RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Col_1, Col_2 ORDER BY Col_1 ) part
FROM   someTable ) st where st.part < 2;
```

Since I was reminded that you can't use the alias in the original where clause, I made a change that will still work, though may not be the most elegant.

Comment: You are right about using `rank() over ()`, but you can't reference an alias (`part`) in the `where` clause this way. You might also consider using `dense_rank()`.